# If W is a finite dimensional i.p.s and V is a subspace of W, and if $T \in L(V,W)$ is the map $Tu=u$, how can I prove $T^* = P_{V}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If W is an inner product space that is also finite dim. and V is a subspace of W, and if $T \in L(V,W)$ is the map $Tu=u$, how can I prove $T^* = P_{V}$? Here $T^*$ is the adjoint operator of $T$ and $P_{V}$ is the orthogonal projection of $V$ onto $W$.

I am trying to do the following:

Let $w \in W$, then $\langle v,T^*w\rangle = \langle Tv,w\rangle = \langle v,w\rangle$

but dont know how to proceed so that I can get that $T^* = P_{V}$. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By what you have shown, $\langle v,T^*w\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle$, i.e. $\langle v,T^*w-w\rangle=0$ for all $v\in V$ and $w\in W$, we have $T^*w-w\in V^\perp$ for each $w\in W$.

Note that $W=V\oplus V^\perp$ by the fact that $V$ is finite dimensional, and $w=T^*w+(w-T^*w)$, where $T^*w\in V$ by definition, and $w-T^*w\in V^\perp$, we have $T^*w=P_Vw$ for all $w\in W$, thus $T^*=P_V$.

Another way to do that is: directly check that $P_V$ is a, therefore the adjoint operator of $T$. It's direct and without any trick.

Comment: Note that $\left<v,T^*w\right>$ is an inner product in space $V$ and $\left<v,w\right>$ is one in $W$.

Comment: How did you get that $T^*w-w\in V^\perp$ for each $w\in W$? Was it like so?: $<v,T*w>-<v,w>=0$ implies $<v,T*w-w>=0$?

Comment: @Shuchang But the author assumed that $V\subseteq W$?

Comment: @user123276 Is it the definition that $x\in V^\perp\iff\forall v\in V\colon\langle x,v\rangle=0$? According to your edit, yes. Edited.

Comment: actually, my definition says that:

$V^\perp = (w \in W: <w,v> = 0  \forall v \in V)$. I noticed that using this definition seems to have the $w,v$ in the wrong spots. Do you know if there was a mistake above? Thanks!